# Modify video render webrtc android

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc

Hi i use webRTC project for android https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC

I want to change `video(life)`. Like OpenCV has `@ovveride` method

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
```

But i can`t find something like this in webRTC

```
videoSource = 
    factory.createVideoSource(VideoCapturerAndroid.create(backCamRec), videoConstraints);
```

`VideoCapturerAndroid` object does not give access to inner methods.